# Summing Kronecker Deltas: Sharp slowdowns for simple sums

Tags: summation, timing

I'm using Mathematica 12.0 Student Edition. I'm a little confused by the length of time Mathematica takes to evaluate certain sums of Kronecker Deltas or Discrete Deltas. Here's a simple example below:

---

My global assumptions are

```
ClearAll["Global'*"]
$Assumptions = M \[Element] PositiveIntegers;
```

When I time the double sum of a Kronecker delta below, I get .171875 seconds:

```
Timing[Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, M}, {j, 1, M}]]
```

When I time a similar sum, I get 14.7656 seconds (!):

```
Timing[Sum[1/2 (1 + KroneckerDelta[i, j]), {i, 1, M}, {j, 1, M}]]
```

---

Why is there a spike in the amount of time Mathematica takes to evaluate this second sum? Could you please give me a general method to speed up the second evaluation?